# Having unique random numbers in more than one variables

Tags: python, random

Is it possible to have more than one variables and each have a unique and distinct random number from one another. The sample range is the same, yet I do not want the variables to have same numbers.

```
import random

A=random.sample(range(1,4),1)
B=random.sample(range(1,4),1)
C=random.sample(range(1,4),1)
```

So the above example, I want A, B and C to have different random numbers. In other words, no two variables must have the same number.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
A, B, C = random.sample(range(1, 4), k=3)
```

As far as I know, does `random.choice` not prevent from having all three Variables containing the same value, while `sample` does assign each value given in the `range` only once each call

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Just a query: what does 'k' do here?

Comment: @Benjamin `k` is an integer value to specify the length of the output. You need 3 different outputs, so `k=3`  If you are satisfied, feel free to mark the answer as accepted so others now, that the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
y = range(1, 4)
x = np.random.choice(y, 3, replace=False)
print(x)
```

> [2 1 3]